# Bluetooth programming in iPhone

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am planning to develop an iPhone application to transfer files/data to/from my Windows Desktop using Bluetooth.

Please let me know whether the programming interface(SDK)is available in iPhone SDK for this purpose.

In Windows Mobile, I can transfer the file either using a FTP profile or writing application on top of Serial Port Profile(RFComm).

Can anybody tell me, whether this can be possible with an iPhone by writing appropriate application. If not, please let me know alternative way to transfer files/data over bluetooth from iPhone to a Windows Desktop PC.

Answer (score 2):

No, FTP or SPP bluetooth profile are not open in iPhone...

Comment: Can i Send raw data by setting up a bluetooth connection(writing application) between Iphone and Windows Desktop ?

Comment: Can we get access to the RFcomm APIs if we join the "made for iPod" program ? If we get access to the RFComm functionalities or SPP, that will help us to proceed. Please let us know if this is possible.

Comment: "made for iPod" program is for accessory and not support FTP or SPP

Comment: Can I make use of 'made for iPhone program' to develop a bluetooth applcation to transfer data to my custom device having bluetooth chip ?

Comment: Yes, it is the aim, but I think you have to pay to access to the program

Answer (score 1):

If you get into the made for ipod program, you might develop a bluetooth dongle for a computer (it can't use the normal one built into the computer as it needs a custom apple chip for encoding).  This is the only method that could do something like what you want over bluetooth and get your app into the app store.  You can implement a similar functionality more readily over wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use the Human Interface Device profile, and have your USB device pretend to be a keyboard. You can then have your app receive text input from the "keyboard". simply encode your data as ASCII encoded hex or base 64 and transmit. Whether or not your app would be allowed in the app store is a different matter.

Comment: That wouldn't work if your goal is, as mine is, to work with serial - bluetooth adapters that support the SPP profile.

Comment: Are there any changes until now?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 requirements to use iOS BT Classic for data transmission over RFCOMM.
1) You need to be enrolled in Apple MFi program.
2) The BT accessory which will be connected to iPhone needs to have a special HW chip called "MFi Coprocessor".

Both requirements need to be satisfied if you are developing FW for the BT accessory.

The latter one is required when you are coding iOS app.
BTW, you will not be able to communicate with Windows machine unless you have a BT dongle with MFi chip inside - see the second requirement.